# Can not access admin links

Tags: navigation, users

I have encountered a weird problem in Drupal 6 in the recent days: I can log in as admin but none of the mysite.com/admin/* links work from GUI.

I still can use drush to enable and disable modules and do other administrative tasks but can not do the same from the admin menu.

None of the other aspects of the site are affected. I cleared all cache, updated the database, performed cron (using drush), and restarted all servers. Alas, no effect. The log messages are not helpful either.  I'm really perplexed and appreciate your help.

Comment: mysite.com/admin/* give you 404 errors ?

Comment: no the error that I get is 503.

Comment: Some more information about your server setup and the log messages would be helpful. A search on drupal.org shows some possible causes are overloaded DB-server, Varnish timeouts...

Comment: Well, as far as I can see the DB is not overloaded. It has a separate server and uses a tiny fraction of max_connection and the serve load is below 1. The web server uses varnish, but I get the error even if I connect DB from 'behind' varnish, where nginx/php5-fpm live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a problem with nginx/php5-fpm settings that timeout prematurely. When I use apache (using another port) the problem does not exist.